# Using rewrite engine to route multiple domains to different paths on one server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have two domains:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
```

I have one Apache 2 server, with a document root `/svr.`

I want the following to occur:

- `domain1.com` routes to the equivalent of `/svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain1`
- `domain2.com` routes to the equivalent of `/svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain2`

I have tried using a `.htaccess` with RewriteEngine in `/svr,` using VirtualHost declarations in sites-available for each hostname and simply using 301 redirects. However, I can't use a simple 301, as the user should still see `domain1.com` in their browser.

I.e. `domain1.com/about-this-site` should map to `/svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain1/about-this-site.`

I can't get RewriteEngine to route the hostnames to their respective endpoints, any advice would be much appreciated. I'm currently attempting to use `HTTP_HOST` in a `.htaccess` in the server root, but the rewrite rules still aren't taking effect.

Ilmiont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive sets the directory from which httpd will serve files and it is allowed in <[VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)> [Context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context), so you can do something like this in your `.conf` files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain1.example.com
  DocumentRoot /svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain1
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain2.example.com
  DocumentRoot /svr/examplepath/thisisadir/param/domain2
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```